# I'm running into a ValueError after creating an hdf5 file with python

Tags: python, hdf5, valueerror, h5py

**I am attempting to create an h5 file for my algorithm and I continue to get the following ValueError:**

- I originally created the file under mode “w” but when that did not
  work I reran it under mode “r+” and now I am running into this error.
- Do I need to rename the file, or can I delete the original h5 file
  and recreate it under the same name?  Any input would be appreciated,
  thanks.

  ```
   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-9-60d1408421e9> in <module>
        9 #Import Data
        10 f = h5py.File("orderbook.hdf5", "r+")
   ---> 11 dset = f.create_dataset("orderbook_dataset", (100,), dtype='i')
        12 
        13 

   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
       146                     group = self.require_group(parent_path)
       147 
   --> 148             dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(group, shape, dtype, data, name, 
   **kwds)
       149             dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
       150             return set

   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, name, chunks, 
   compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, 
   track_times, external, track_order, dcpl, allow_unknown_filter)
       135 
       136 
   --> 137     dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, name, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl)
       138 
       139     if (data is not None) and (not isinstance(data, Empty)):

   h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

   h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

   h5py/h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.create()

   ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)
  ```

Comment: It's saying that a `dataset` with "orderbook_dataset" name already exists in the file.  What does you know about the existing one?  Do you want to keep it?  Write new data to it?  Is the shape and dtype right?  You have the file; you have to decide what to do with it.

Comment: @hpaulj I apologize, my question is more along the lines of: I have an existing file. What do I need to do to run my code so that I can keep this file and the rest of my code runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my question by removing line 11 after the file was created using mode "w".  This allowed the file to be read with mode "r+" without 'f.create_dataset' being called.

```
  9 #Import Data
  10 f = h5py.File("orderbook.hdf5", "r+")
 ---> 11 dset = f.create_dataset("orderbook_dataset", (100,), dtype='i')
```